# How to enable Flutter hot reload in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

### Scenario

I'm working through the base counter app (after `flutter create`)

### Expected Functionality

I want to enable hot reload in VS Code:

```
1. increase the count
2. change the primary color + save file
3.1 see the color change
3.2 see the count stay the same (preserving state)
```

### Actual Behavior

In all cases (saving, hitting r(R) in the console, even hitting the lightning icon) I get a `Restarted application in Xms` and a hot **restart**.

```
1. increase the count
2. change the primary color + save file
3.1 color changes
3.2 count is reset to 0 (state is lost)
```

### What I tried

- switching between manual and automatic save settings
- setting `dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave` to `all`
- setting `dart.hotReloadOnSave` to `all`
- launching the app in `debug` and `run` modes (`ctrl+F5` and `F5`)

### My setup

- Flutter `v3.3.2`
- VS Code `v1.71`
- Flutter extension `v3.48.0`
- Dart extension `v3.48.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot Reload is only available for non-web devices (desktop, mobile). On web, any calls to Hot Reload will instead trigger Hot Restart (since it's the closest functionality available).

Hot Reload for web is tracked in this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041

Comment: As described in the question I tried running the app through VS Code and through the terminal in debug/run modes. I also tried hitting the lightning button. Neither approaches result in a hot reload.

Comment: @ANDREYDEN apologies, I saw you mention Shift+R and had assumed you'd only been running from the terminal. Re-reading I see the issue is that you're getting a Hot Restart when you expect a Hot Reload. Can you confirm what device you're running on? Right now, web/Chrome does not support a stateful reload, so all reloads will be a full restart unfortunately. This is tracked in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I've tried this on an Android emulator and it worked. Do you mind re-posting/editing your answer so I can mark it as accepted?